# i am getting parsererror in ajax call to json SyntaxError: Invalid character

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

here is my code

```
   $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/manageUsers.do",
       cache: false,
       data:{ "resultType": "json", "submit": $.i18n.prop('esadmin.manage.users.delete-btn'), "OID": oid },
       invokedata: { "OID": oid, "username": username },
       contentType: "application/json",
       dataType: "text",
       success:  deleteUserSuccess,
       error: deleteUserError
   });
```

Comment: You are calling ajax as text dataType: "text" and saying json???

Answer (score 0):

Try calling it like this

```
 $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/manageUsers.do",
       cache: false,
       data:{ "resultType": "json", "submit": $.i18n.prop('esadmin.manage.users.delete-btn'), "OID": oid },
       invokedata: { "OID": oid, "username": username },
       contentType: "application/json",
       dataType: "json",
       success:  deleteUserSuccess,
       error: deleteUserError
  });
```